# Sitecore session timeout

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to increase my Sitecore session timeout for CMS.

I have changed the below three changes but still it is not working.

```
<setting name="Authentication.ClientSessionTimeout" value="180" />

<authentication mode="None">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="180" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
  sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password="
  cookieless="false" timeout="180" />
```

Can anyone please help or have any idea on this?

Comment: Are you trying to expand sessions for content authors on the CMS, or session timeout in general for all visitors to the site?

Comment: For content authors on the CMS

Comment: You're missing a few points mentioned here. https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/53/

Comment: In these three places only, he told to edit the value

Comment: KeepAlive etc..

Comment: I tried that also, but no luck

Comment: You may want to specify Sitecore version as well... just in case this happens to be an Identity Server thing, but Identity Server only applies to newer versions.

Comment: i have sitecore 9.3 and it has identity server.